# VB.NET - Why does my Excel read skip the first line?

Tags: vb.net, excel

There is a program that reads an Excel file using OLEDB and converts it to a tab delimited text file. This loop handles the conversion.

```
While reader.Read
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Try
                While (True)
                    temp = reader(count).ToString + ControlChars.Tab
                    output_file.Write(temp)
                    count += 1
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                output_file.WriteLine()
            End Try


        End While
```

Not the most elegant code for sure, but it reads in each cell one by one, then throws an exception at the end of the row to write a newline. The only problem is that it skips the first line of the Excel document. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the first row of the Excel file a header row?

Comment: @Tim It does have header information in it, yes, but is there a specific setting to designate a row as a header in Excel? I don't really use excel much (I don't even have it myself, I'm using the Open Office viewer right now)

Comment: I don't know about a setting to designate the row as a header, but if the first row is simply a header row I wouldn't worry about it, unless you wanted to duplicate it your tab-delimited file.  Let me do a little looking around on that and see what I can find, if anything.

Comment: @Tim unfortunately, the data that I need the most from this Excel doc is the header, so getting that first line is essential

Comment: can you post the connection string you're using to read the Excel doc?

Comment: @Tim All fixed. Apparently I needed to add HDR=No to my connection string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a more elegant solution, try this:

```
While reader.Read()

    For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
        output_file.Write(reader(i).ToString() + ControlChars.Tab)
    Next

    output_file.WriteLine()
End While
```

Read each line from the reader, and process the fields in the row in a FOR loop, using the number of fields in the row (.FieldCount).

After each FOR loop is complete, end the line in the file.

Repeat for each row in the reader.

It's good practice to **not** use exceptions to handle events in code that can otherwise be handled (e.g., throwing a handling a FileNotFoundException - or throwing one - rather than simply doing a File.Exits check).\

**UPDATE**
Did a little googling, and it appears that you can include/exclude the header via the connection string:

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";`

Note the HDR=Yes part.  According to [Connection strings for Excel](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) this is used to indicate whether or not the first row is the header.

Another thing you might try is seeing if the reader's fields have values in their Name property, using reader.GetName(int index), where index is the zero-based ordinal of the column (field).

Comment: Yes, that is nicer. I use the while loop with an exception only because I didn't know how to get the Field count so easily. I will make this change though, thanks

Comment: I stopped using exceptions to handle things like that, but this is a utility left over from my early days of programming, so the bad practice still persists here.

Comment: It works now, though now it has a new, odd error. It reads the header cells, except for two. Just two in the middle of it. Stepping through the code, I find that the database read is just returning "" for that particular read. I'll have to do some investigating. Edit: Seems to have something to do with the data in that column being in a data format. Ah well, I can get this fixed. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Oh yea, and I should point out, your more elegant solution runs something like  a thousand times faster than the one with the exceptions